# Link to download pdf from webform email

Tags: 7, webforms, files

I have created a webform, after the submession the customer is sent the registration confirmation e-mail.  How do I include in this email a link to download a pdf ?

Comment: what does registration confirmation email mean ? the email send from webform on submission ?

Comment: If we are talking about a webform, then under the "webform" tab on the webform node there will be an "email" section. You can add it directly to the email text. The link will be /node/[nid]/webform/emails . The "registration confirmation" part is a bit ambiguous. There is a user registration confirmation also, but I'm guessing that you are referring to the webform being a type of event registration form? In the case of user registration, there is a section under /admin/config/people/accounts where you can modify the emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !

All i want was how make the customer can download the mail as pdf by one click on link "Télécharger ici votre confirmation":

[image]

So i used the library jsPDF to generate mail as pdf